# Dont insert if aggregator calculations is null

Tags: sqlite

I have these two tables:

```
VALIDATED_DATA

CALCULATED_DATA
```

I need to insert aggregated values into the `CALCULATED_DATA` table every min. Currently I have this script running:

```
INSERT INTO CALCULATED_DATA(AvgBatteryVoltage, MaxBatteryVoltage, MinBatteryVoltage, 
                                                AvgTemperature, MaxTemperature, MinTemperature,
                                                AvgHumidity, MaxHumidity, MinHumidity,
                                                AvgNoiseLevel, MaxNoiseLevel, MinNoiseLevel, 
                                                MaxOccurance, MinOccurance, ReportedToCloud)
SELECT 
        AVG(BatteryVoltage) as AvgBatteryVoltage, MAX(BatteryVoltage) AS MaxBatteryVoltage, MIN(BatteryVoltage) AS MinBatteryVoltage,
        AVG(Temperature) AS AvgTemperature, MAX(Temperature) AS MaxTemperature, MIN(Temperature) AS MinTemperature,
        AVG(Humidity) AS AvgHumidity, MAX(Humidity) AS MaxHumidity, MIN(Humidity) AS MinHumidity,
        AVG(NoiseLevel) AS AvgNoiseLevel, MAX(NoiseLevel) AS MaxNoiseLevel, MIN(NoiseLevel) AS MinNoiseLevel,
        MAX(Occurance), MIN(Occurance), 0
FROM VALIDATED_DATA 
WHERE
    IsProcessed = 0 AND
    (BatteryVoltage NOT NULL OR
    Temperature NOT NULL OR 
    Humidity NOT NULL OR
    NoiseLevel NOT NULL)
```

The thing is that there aren't any values where in the `VALIDATED_DATA` table where the IsProcessed is equal to 0 it will still insert the aggregated values as NULL's.

Is there a way to validate that if the aggregated values is null don't insert or should that be a not null constraint on the `CALCULATED_DATA` columns?

EDIT!

```
INSERT INTO CALCULATED_DATA(AvgBatteryVoltage, MaxBatteryVoltage, MinBatteryVoltage, 
                                                AvgTemperature, MaxTemperature, MinTemperature,
                                                AvgHumidity, MaxHumidity, MinHumidity,
                                                AvgNoiseLevel, MaxNoiseLevel, MinNoiseLevel, 
                                                MaxOccurance, MinOccurance, ReportedToCloud)
SELECT 
        AVG(BatteryVoltage) as AvgBatteryVoltage, MAX(BatteryVoltage) AS MaxBatteryVoltage, MIN(BatteryVoltage) AS MinBatteryVoltage,
        AVG(Temperature) AS AvgTemperature, MAX(Temperature) AS MaxTemperature, MIN(Temperature) AS MinTemperature,
        AVG(Humidity) AS AvgHumidity, MAX(Humidity) AS MaxHumidity, MIN(Humidity) AS MinHumidity,
        AVG(NoiseLevel) AS AvgNoiseLevel, MAX(NoiseLevel) AS MaxNoiseLevel, MIN(NoiseLevel) AS MinNoiseLevel,
        MAX(Occurance), MIN(Occurance), 0
FROM VALIDATED_DATA 
WHERE
    IsProcessed = 0 AND
    (BatteryVoltage NOT NULL OR
    Temperature NOT NULL OR 
    Humidity NOT NULL OR
    NoiseLevel NOT NULL)
GROUP BY VALIDATED_DATA.IsProcessed;
```

The above SQL made it for avoiding the code to insert an empty row.

Comment: My feeling is that your intended `WHERE` logic really belongs in a `HAVING` clause.  But I'm not sure if SQLite permits `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do you have an example of using a having in this case? You can try in MySQL syntax and then I can test it on SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use aggregation functions without GROUP BY, you always get one output row.
When you use aggregation functions with GROUP BY, you get one output row per group, so you get no rows if there is no group.

Just add a GROUP BY on your existing filter:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT AVG(...), ...
FROM ...
WHERE IsProcessed = 0 AND ...
GROUP BY IsProcessed;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This actually worked like a charm!